# echo - Syntax error: Bad substitution

Tags: linux, bash

A script with a problem:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 skl="test"
  4 # get length
  5 leng=$(expr length $skl)
  6 # get desired length
  7 leng=$(expr 22 - $leng)
  8
  9 # get desired string
 10 str=$(printf "%${leng}s" "-")
 11
 12 # replace empty spaces
 13 str=$(echo "${str// /-}")
 14
 15 # output
 16 echo "$str  obd: $skl  $str"
 17
```

but it outputs:

```
name.sh: 13: Syntax error: Bad substitution
```

please help, thanks
I would be very grateful :)

Comment: for me, I was getting the syntax error as a result of a typo in a variable name `${$variable}` . It needed just one `$` to be valid syntax.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following line:

```
str=$(echo "${str// /-}")
```

is resulting into `Syntax error: Bad substitution` because you are **not** executing your script using `bash`.  You are either executing your script using `sh` or `dash` which is causing the error.

---

EDIT: In order to *fix* your script to enable it to work with `sh` and `dash` in addition to `bash`, you could replace the following lines:

```
# get desired string
str=$(printf "%${leng}s" "-")

# replace empty spaces
str=$(echo "${str// /-}")
```

with

```
str=$(printf '=%.0s' $(seq $leng) | tr '=' '-')
```

Comment: I will now use bash. Thanks

Comment: because your solution gives me 

`==================  obd: test  ==================` instead `--------------  obd: test  --------------`

Comment: @andrej See the edit above.  It should now result in `-------------- obd: test --------------`.

Answer (score 3):

Take out all unnecessary expr calls, using pure BASH features:

```
#!/bin/bash

skl="test"
# get length
leng=${#skl}
# get desired length
leng=$((22 - leng))

# get desired string
str=$(printf "%${leng}s" "-")

# replace empty spaces
str=$(echo "${str// /-}")

# output
echo "$str  obd: $skl  $str"
```

Comment: using `sh` I get 

    name.sh: 7: arith: syntax error: "22 - leng"

Comment: You are using bash shebang then you should be using bash to run your script instead of sh