# Wrong syntax to use file content as parameters

Tags: shell, busybox

In a CI pipeline I am running kaniko executor command (using busybox).
Beside two parameters I want to get all `--build-arg` values using a build.args file. The file has a simple key/value content

```
/kaniko/executor \
  --context $path \
  --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE \
  $(for i in `cat build.args`; do out+="--build-arg $i " ; done; echo $out;out="")
```

*build.args*

```
name="application-name"
version="1.2.3"
port="3000"
title="Great image"
description="This is a wonderful description of nothing"
```

But I do get multiple error like `eval: line 149: out+=--build-arg name="application-name" : not found` for each value. What am I missing and why is my code wrong?

---

*Update*

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.6.0-debug
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"auth\":\"$(echo -n ${CI_REGISTRY_USER}:${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} | base64)\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - |
      apps=$(cat $AFFECTED_APPS)
      for item in $apps; do
        domain=${item%-*}
        app=${item##*-}
        path=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/apps/${domain}/${app}
        echo "Build docker image ${item}"
        ${$CI_PROJECT_DIR}/tools/scripts/build_docker.sh ${path}/build.args \
          --context $path \
          --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE \
          --build-arg BUILD_DATE=$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
      done
```

Comment: Busybox sh doesn't support `+=`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oh. What would be a busybox solution?

Comment: Off the cuff, something like `out="$out --build-arg $i"`, but that's still suffering from all the unquoted expansions, so it's not super safe to use. https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-sh-bible might have pointers for a better method, but I don't see anything right now.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Could you explain a bit why it could be unsafe?

Comment: "Unsafe" isn't the right word, but "not robust" - unquoted expansions can have all kinds of side effects because of word splitting and filename expansion ("globbing"). If you show the contents of `build.args`, it might be possible to suggest a better solution, maybe using positional parameters, or processing the contents of the file with sed or so.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The structure of build.args is shown in the post. So there is always a string, but the last two could have spaces. The values are used as LABEL value in the Dockerfile: `ARG DESCRIPTION` and `LABEL org.opencontainers.image.description=$DESCRIPTION` So the spaces are a problem. All other values should be fine.

Comment: Oh, right, it's right there! Let me try and see if I can do something with positional parameters.

Comment: (glenn's solution is pretty much the best I would have been able to come up with ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you do the shell stuff in a shell script, using the positional parameters as Benjamin suggests:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
    set -- "$@" --build-arg "$line"
done < build.args

/kaniko/executor "$@"
```

Then the CI pipeline step would be

```sh
/path/to/executor.sh --context "$path" --destination "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
```

---

To pass the build.args file as a parameter, I would do this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
build_args=$1
shift

while IFS= read -r line; do
    set -- "$@" --build-arg "$line"
done < "$build_args"

/kaniko/executor "$@"
```

```sh
/path/to/executor.sh /path/to/build.args --context "$path" --destination "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
```

Comment: The path to build.args has to be dynamic, so I have to pass it to the script. How would I do that?

Comment: Thanks. But I do get the error `syntax error: bad substitution`. I'm running the script in busybox. Is this causing the error?

Comment: That seems to indicate you're doing something bash-specific. Busybox sh is not bash. -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/20323738/7552

Comment: Hmm... In my CI stage I'm using the kaniko:debug image, which has busybox (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#debug-image). I don't see the problem :-(

Comment: Are you using this same code?

Comment: I updated the post with the complete code - which I think is the same...

Comment: `${$CI_PROJECT_DIR}` is wrong, remove the inner `$`